# WPF Designer Never Loads Properly

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have an WPF app, all seems to run fine with one exception - the designer rarely, if ever, loads correctly. Usually complaining about `Undefined CLR namespace.` and then saying it can't find a few of my `local:` defined controls.

Is this just a defect in the designer or Visual Studios code generation or actually systemic of something wrong with my application?

Comment: I had a project that was giving me trouble and I just created a new project and copy pasted the moving parts.

Comment: Have you built your project? The designer will load the last successfully built version of your project.

Comment: @JoelLucsy yea i build it all the time (successfully). Then it'll be fine for awhile, then go back to bad.

Answer (score 0):

In your code can be an error which occurs only in design time. It is possible to debug it. See [How to: Debug a Designer Load Failure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee856616.aspx). Shortly you need another instance of Visual Studio and attach it to the one displaying your wpf app. You can even try to follow the error to its roots with [How to: Debug .NET Framework Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx).

I had a similar problem and I successfully tracked it down to DataContextChanged event handler and got rid of it.