# Null Pointer Exception in Silverlight Business Application

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, installation, null-pointer

I am new to silverlight. I have just created a new silverlight business application in visual studio. But, I cannot see the pages in designer mode. When ever i choose designer mode, it is throwing null pointer exception, rather than the designer.  But, I can code in manually and when I run, the pages are getting displayed in browser.

I clearly understand that, it might be problem with vs/silverlight plugins. How can I solve this.? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Setup
Windows 7
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
Silverlight 4 developers runtime
Silverlight tools April10

Comment: Visual seems unable to resolve a part of your XAML code. Maybe you could show what you did ? You could also try to update to Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that silverlight behave the same way as WPF.  There can be an error in your code behind which is not present in rutime. See [WPF Designer Never Loads Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10043544/669527).